# SQL Error in INSERT and UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have fought with this the last two hours and my head hurts..
I get this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7
```

This is my table https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngsjo.png

This is my query:

```
    if(!is_int($_POST['x']) || !is_int($_POST['x'])) break;

    $q = mysql_query("
        INSERT INTO `bit-board`
        (value, type, x, y) 
        VALUES(
            '".$_POST['post-it']."',
            'post-it',
            '".$_POST['x']."',
            '".$_POST['y']."'
        )"
    );
    echo mysql_error() ? mysql_error:mysql_insert_id();
```

And the second one:

```
    if(!is_int(intval($_POST['x'])) || !is_int(intval($_POST['x'])) || !is_int(intval($_POST['id']))) break;

    $q = mysql_query("
        UPDATE `bit-board`
        SET 
            value = '".$_POST['post-it']."',
            type = 'post-it',
            x = '".$_POST['x']."',
            y = '".$_POST['y']."'
        WHERE id = '".$_POST[id]."'
    ");
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post your query?

Comment: What is your SQL? We can't help you if we don't know what caused the error.

Comment: When your question is "I have an error in my SQL. What's wrong?" and you don't post your SQL, it's pretty much impossible to get an answer.

Comment: Sorry, thought the error would do, posted above

Comment: Don't put `'bit-board'` into quotes: `INSERT INTO bit-board ...`

Comment: You probably should escape your data. Otherwise you risk SQL injection. `mysql_query` is also in the process of being deprecated.

Comment: @ypercube: the dash is a special character, so the name has to be quoted just not with single quotes. Either double quotes (if MySQL is configured to run ANSI mode) or those dreaded backticks.

Comment: I did this in top of my ajax.php file 
foreach($_POST as &$post) {
 $post = mysql_real_escape_string($post); 
}

Answer (score 0):

X and Y are floats, so don't put quotes around a numeric value.
Also check the comment from @a_horse_with_no_name about quoting the table name.

```
$q = mysql_query("
            INSERT INTO `bit-board`
            (value, type, x, y) 
            VALUES(
            '".$_POST['post-it']."',
            'post-it',
            ".$_POST['x'].",
            ".$_POST['y']."
        )"
    );
```

(Not tested)